# Typescript error in `this` context in bound & returned function

Tags: javascript, typescript, binding, this

I've a function `URLBuilder` that works as a module(it returns an object that contain various functions and those functions are bound well with a context object so the `this` binding works as expected, and we can access `this` inside these functions correctly)

My problem is why typescript didn't understand the `this` binding of functions inside the return object of the `URLBuilder`? Even though I try adding a return type manually Typescript complain `when using the URLBuilder` that it cannot accept the function without `this` context.

How can we let typescript understand the `this` for this bound function inside the returned object?

Typescript Error that I want to resolve is:

```
The 'this' context of type 'URLBuilderAPI' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'ExecutionContext'.
```

```
interface URLBuilderOptions {
    baseURL: string,
}

interface ExecutionContext {
    options: URLBuilderOptions,
    predefinedValues: { protocol: string },
}


/************************* */

function generateRequestURL(this: ExecutionContext, customOptions: { subRoute: string }) {

    return `${this.predefinedValues.protocol}:${this.options.baseURL}/api/v3/${customOptions.subRoute}/some-url`;
}

/************************* */


function URLBuilder(options: URLBuilderOptions) {

    const predefinedValues = {
        protocol: 'https',
    }

    const context = {
        options,
        predefinedValues,
    }

    const API = {
        generateRequestURL: generateRequestURL.bind(context)
    }

    return API;
}


/*********************** */

// 1st try

let urlInstance = URLBuilder({ baseURL: 'www.url.com' });

urlInstance.generateRequestURL({}); 
// typescript cannot understand function params and auto suggest them!

/*********************** */


interface URLBuilderAPI {
    generateRequestURL: typeof generateRequestURL,
}

function URLBuilder_WithReturnTypes(options: URLBuilderOptions): URLBuilderAPI {

    const predefinedValues = {
        protocol: 'https',
    }

    const context = {
        options,
        predefinedValues,
    }

    const API = {
        generateRequestURL: generateRequestURL.bind(context)
    }

    return API;
}


/*********************** */

// 2nd try

let urlInstanceWithTypes = URLBuilder_WithReturnTypes({ baseURL: 'www.url.com' });

urlInstanceWithTypes.generateRequestURL({ subRoute: '/test/' })
/**
 * typescript error:
 * The 'this' context of type 'URLBuilderAPI' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'ExecutionContext'.
 */
/*********************** */
```

Comment: What is wrong with the first version ? I see suggestions in `generateRequestURL`. Do you use `strictBindCallApply`? Because if not  then bind will return `any`

Comment: I didn't use `strictBindCallApply`, I'll test it now

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `strictBindCallApply` compiler option, then code will work as expected, and you will get completions on your first attempt ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)). Without `strictBindCallApply`, `bind` will return `any`, so you will not get any checking for the parameters to the function ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictBindCallApply=false#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))

If you don't want to enable this option you can use a type assertion on the result of `bind` to get a type that will have the same parameters and return type, but remove the type of `this`:

```
....
    const API = {
        generateRequestURL: generateRequestURL.bind(context) as OmitThisParameter<typeof generateRequestURL>
    }
...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictBindCallApply=false#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFUBKAZAQgVxABsATWAeQAcIQB7MAZ1QG9hV3UAjBBqLbAFyoGEGOADmAGmABfYKEixEKVAFEAHlCT4a9AML1o6iCzYda1OoyH8CxMjCq7G0jqkowoZOOC8A1BCJ8KAYhZncYWghaJFoiIRExMHFUGWk5eQB6ACpcvPyCwvzUbMz5OHwwJGdUcSgwWARoTCgAR2CRfgAKCAALEFC1TW1nA0VjSVRtEVoAWycrQfCGfE5MWh0oBNEJVIBKUzN2Twh8GDBUAAMAEmY+gYA6Dy8oHwaSAKCQp8jo2KIZAJbvcGA8LM5QdxePwZJkEJQQJkAG4AZkyt2m0XmlnooJWaw20FhDDmUAAtGciJcANyyLJFBmM7IlMrlSrVKwYHB2UiwLrgxY2bmEXmOHGMA6sI5TXEmZ7eXwfQIdVAAXlMbjcHiiMTiQgA5L0IBBKAx9a4OBk3LFGCYbUYTOrWJrzOKGBaXfLXorPh0Pal5NbZagAIIABQAkmqNS7avVGs02h0IPwhHUGjAmlAWu0QimcA9OOASF17VBjAceKhyLMQBAACr9BhhhCZ2ZQaAwAA8EAAnpQoLQ4HGM1mc8n+AA+aVWjgnM4XcMR2kZYA5Jkb5mlLKZVAARhEqFEvfkRA7qEpEdtCCqaHVthFDi64ShfBwBoA7l+HpSHrFZvq+y0sAl7XreDzpgm2ZJnm3ThJaezUuwmS7rAkQwEwCDiAg4DAEAA)

You could also define your interface to omit the `this` parameter:

```
interface URLBuilderAPI {
    generateRequestURL: OmitThisParameter<typeof generateRequestURL>,
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-maUsplUAATGAJCoKIxryEQ+qoJSwo5ggVRQIGfThmaTBljy9iwAGQYhs+KGRuEUJ8HuqB1gA7hRDyUg8sSzHW+y0sAMFwQhSG9PhoISjaMp2vK3TLKs6ybPWmTQCImT0TId6fmwzImqhSBiNQqCwJEMACLJqAamgdYgvR17GKgFqgRGpEYT6K70QMqBgFEqA8AwIDiGACCcJBoG0Kgep9LQJB1kwumavRxnyTpGhaDoVhjH2dYPLJZSft+jIskAA)

Comment: It works, thank you. 
Just to know if another options exist...can we make an interface type that can be defined outside the function and use it as the return type of the function?

Comment: @LouayAlosh added a version with an interface and used the `OmitThisParameter` instead of using `Parameters` and `ReturnType`